# JavaScript autostart method on creation mimic init?

Tags: javascript, oop, initialization, custom-events

I'm learning my way through OOP in JavaScript and have hit a snag, when I create an instance of a Class I want to be able for it to run a set of internal functions.

From what I can tell it is similar to the idea of the init function in many other languages.

A Simple example would be:

```
function human(name, age){

this.name = name;
this.age = age;

this.init = function(){
    console.log("hi my name is "+this.name+" and I am "+this.age+" years old.");
}//end of this.init

}//end of class human

var fred = new Human("fred", 30);
fred.init();
```

I want fred.init to run automatically without it having to be explicitly called. I understand it is an event so I thought of an EventListener something like:

```
this.addEventListener("initialization", this.init);
```

being put inside the class but I have not found the correct event. I have started to look into custom events but I am at a total loss here plus I still wouldn't know how to describe the initilisation even if I do wrap my head around it.

If someone could just point me in the right direction (if not the full solution) I would be most grateful.

thanks

Zen

p.s. a link to a custom events for dummies guide would also be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I am a bit of a dumbo, if anyone else has this problem, the solution is dead simple:

```
function human(name, age){

  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

  this.init = function(){
    console.log("hi my name is "+this.name+" and I am "+this.age+" years old.");
  }//end of this.init

  this.init();

}//end of class human
var fred = new Human("fred", 30);
```

All you have to do is call the method inside of the class definition using the "this" iden